# Difference hours Joda time in Java

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I've a problem with Joda Time...
So, I'm developing a time difference method and I would be calculate the interval beetwen 2 times...
I must develop 2 cases but I don't undestand how can I do:

1° case - interval

```
date1 = "01/02/2014 9:00";
date2 = "01/02/2014 18:00";

Expected result: 9 hours
```

2° case - difference time

```
date1 = "9:00";
date2 = "1:00";

Expected result: 8
```

how can I do? I'm very confused...

thank you guys!!

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Hours.html#hoursBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,%20org.joda.time.ReadablePartial%29

Comment: You should consider time zone as that affects the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class HourDeltaCalculator {

  // assuming you want month first like in US-date-format?
  private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm"); 

  public static int hoursBetween(String date1, String date2) {
    LocalDateTime ldt1 = FORMATTER.parseLocalDateTime(date1);
    LocalDateTime ldt2 = FORMATTER.parseLocalDateTime(date2);

    return Hours.hoursBetween(ldt1, ldt2).getHours();
  }
}
```

This code yields:

```
String date1 = "01/02/2014 9:00";
String date2 = "01/02/2014 18:00";
System.out.println(hoursBetween(date1, date2)); // 9
```

Your other case can be done in a very similar way, but with `LocalTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`. By the way, the difference between 09:00 and 01:00 is not `8`, but `-8`.

Comment: thanks man!! :) your reply is very clearly! I've a last question: how can I sum 2 times over 24h? In example: 15:00 + 15:00 = 30:00... :)
Thanks so much! :)

Comment: if you interprete 15:00 as point in time then addition of two points in time does not make sense, but you might interprete the arguments as length in time that is *duration*s. Then you can look at the classes `PeriodFormatter` and `Duration`-method [plus()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#plus(org.joda.time.ReadableDuration)).

Comment: Yes, I'm developing an android app to calculate the ordinary time and extra time of my job and I need to sum/subtract hours as "normal" number...in example: I need to calculate the hours that I worked in a week...So, the results is greater than 24h! :)